SwiftData @Query in ObservableObject
I have the following ObservableObject:
class ExercisesManager: ObservableObject {
    let modelContext: ModelContext
    @Published var exercises: [Exercise] = []
    var errorMessage: String?
    
    init(modelContext: ModelContext) {
        self.modelContext = modelContext
        fetch()
    }
    
    func fetch() {
        let sort = [SortDescriptor(\Exercise.name)]
        let fetchDescriptor = FetchDescriptor<Exercise>(sortBy: sort)
        do {
            exercises = try modelContext.fetch(fetchDescriptor)
        } catch {
            errorMessage = "DEBUG: Failed getting exercises: \(error.localizedDescription)"
        }
    }

I inject it in the top most view of the app. When I do operations such as adding, deleting or updating an exercise, it is not reflected or saved in the model context, even after specifically calling save. I use the object in various fews as follows:
@EnvironmentObject private var manager: ExercisesManager
@State private var exercises: [Exercise] = []


init() {
    ....
}

var body: some View {
    ....
        .onAppear { exercises = manager.exercises }
}

The reason for doing this is that calling @Query on each view introduced significant lag into my app, so I use @Query to load the exercises at the top most level and just access them wherever I need to in the app. I suspect that some reference is not being updated, since whenever I use @Query it works perfectly but with this solution, closing and reopening the app leads to changes being lost.

Can you give more information on your view structure when you were using @Query in views?

You have created a second copy of exercises array as a State in the second struct. And it only copied the variable on appear. You can use the array from manager object and directly make the modifications there?

Yes this is confusing, you have two sources of truth with the two exercises properties and then you mention using a @Query at the top level view so that is a possible third source of truth.

Perhaps try again with @Query and fix the lag with many small View
